# Explanation of Proof of Second-Derivative Test for Local Extrema

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

My textbook introduces the following theorem:

> **Theorem** 5 Second-Derivative Test for Local Extrema
>
> If $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^3$, $\mathbf{x}_0 \in U$ is a critical point of $f$, and the Hessian $Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)$ is positive-definite, then $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a relative minimum of $f$. Similarly, if $Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)$ is negative-definite, then $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a relative maximum.

It then goes on to say the following:

> Actually, we shall prove that the extrema given by this criterion are strict. A relative maximum $\mathbf{x}_0$ is said to be **strict** if $f(\mathbf{x}) < f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ for nearby $\mathbf{x} \not= \mathbf{x}_0$. A strict relative minimum is defined similarly. Also, the theorem is valid even if $f$ is only $C^2$, but we have assumed $C^3$ for simplicity.
>
> The proof of theorem $5$ requires Taylor's theorem and the following result from linear algebra.
>
> **Lemma** 1 If $B = [b_{ij}]$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix, and if the associated quadratic function
>
> $$H: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (h_1, \dots, h_n) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j$$
>
> is positive-definite, then there is a constant $M > 0$ such that for all $\mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^n$;
>
> $$H(\mathbf{h}) \ge M || \mathbf{h} ||^2.$$

The proof of theorem 5 is as follows:

> **proof of theorem** 5 Recall that if $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^3$ and $\mathbf{x}_0 \in U$ is a critical point, Taylor's theorem may be expressed in the form
>
> $$f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0) = Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{h}) + R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h}),$$
>
> where $\dfrac{R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h})}{|| \mathbf{h} ||^2} \to 0$ as $\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}$.
>
> Because $Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)$ is positive-definite, Lemma 1 assures us of a constant $M > 0$ such that for all $\mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^n$
>
> $$Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{h}) \ge M || \mathbf{h} ||^2.$$
>
> Because $\dfrac{R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h})}{|| \mathbf{h} ||^2} \to 0$ as $\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that for $0 < || \mathbf{h} || < \delta$
>
> $$| R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h}) | < M || \mathbf{h} ||^2.$$
>
> Thus, $0 < Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{h}) + \mathbf{R}_2 ( \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h}) = f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ for $0 < || \mathbf{h} || < \delta$, so that $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a relative minimum; in fact, a strict relative minimum.
>
> The proof in the negative-definite case is similar, or else follows by applying the preceding to $-f$, and is left as an exercise.

The problem I'm having with this proof is that, although I managed to follow it, I don't see how it specifically says/demonstrates anything about relative minimums or strict relative minimums. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain/clarify this.

EDIT: For the sake of clarity, I will also include the following information:

1. > **Theorem** 3 Second-Order Taylor Formula

> Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ have continuous partial derivatives of third order. Then we may write
>
> $$f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) = f(\mathbf{x}_0) + \sum_{i = 1}^n h_i \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}(\mathbf{x}_0) + \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n h_i h_j \dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_i}\partial{x_j}}(\mathbf{x}_0) + R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h}),$$
>
> where $\dfrac{R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h})}{|| \mathbf{h} ||^2} \to 0$ as $\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}$ and the second sum is over all $i$'s and $j$'s between $1$ and $n$ (so there are $n^2$ terms).

2. > Suppose that $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has second-order continuous derivatives $\dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_i}\partial{x_j}}(\mathbf{x}_0)$, for $i, j = 1, \dots, n$, at a points $\mathbf{x}_0 \in U$. The **Hessian of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}_0$** is the quadratic function defined by

> \begin{align} Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{h}) &= \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n \dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_i}\partial{x_j}}(\mathbf{x}_0) h_i h_j \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2} [h_1, \dots, h_n] \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} & \ldots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_n}\\
> \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n\partial x_1}& \ldots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n^2}\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} h_1 \\ \vdots \\ h_n
> \end{matrix}\right] \end{align}

3. > A quadratic function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is called **positive-definite** if $g(\mathbf{h}) \ge 0$ for all $\mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g(\mathbf{h}) = 0$ only for $\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{0}$. Similarly, $g$ is **negative-definite** if $g(\mathbf{h}) \le 0$ and $g(\mathbf{h}) = 0$ for $\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{0}$ only.

Comment: What textbook is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace $| R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h}) | < M \| \mathbf{h} \|^2$ by
$$| R_2(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h}) | \leq {M\over2} \| \mathbf{h} \|^2\qquad\bigl(\|{\bf h}\|<\delta\bigr)\ .$$
Then
$$f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0) = Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{h}) + R_2 ( \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h})   \geq{M\over2} \| \mathbf{h} \|^2>0 \qquad \bigl(0<\|{\bf h}\|<\delta\bigr)\ .$$
This shows that the difference $f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ is strictly positive when $0<\|{\bf h}\|<\delta$. By the very definition of "strict local minimum" this formula (more or less the same as the formula in your book) exhibits the required behavior of $f$: At every point ${\bf x}_0+{\bf h}$ with $0<\|{\bf h}\|<\delta$ the function $f$ assumes a strictly larger value than at ${\bf x}_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see why $f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ being strictly positive for $0<\|{\bf h}\|<\delta$ means that $f$ assumes a strict local minimum at ${\bf x}_0$? I also don't see how $$f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0) = Hf(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{h}) + \mathbf{R}_2 ( \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{h})>{M\over2} \| \mathbf{h} \|^2 \qquad \bigl(\|{\bf h}\|<\delta\bigr)\ $$ implies the above?

Comment: I spent many minutes thinking about your answer. You just almost exactly restated what was from the textbook, without explaining anything extra. If one doesn't understand the textbook proof, then how is it reasonable to expect someone to understand something that is almost exactly the same?

Comment: I made one last edit in the attempt to make things clear for you.

Comment: Your edit helped me understand the proof. The value of the function $f$ at our new point, $f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h})$, minus the value of our function at the original point, $f(\mathbf{x}_0)$, gives $f(\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}_0)$. Since this difference is always positive, it must be the case that the value of the function at the original point (the critical point) is a strict local minimum, since [...]

Comment: [...] any deviation of the function from this original point, whilst still in a neighbourhood of the original point (which is why we have $|| \mathbf{h} || < \delta$) leads to an approximation that is positive. This becomes intuitive when thought of geometrically.